# How can I define CLASSPATH variable

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

For a school assignment I need to add a folder to my classpath. It says that I should do this by adding a line to the file `.bashrc`. However, this file doesn't appear to exist in my computer. I also read something about a file called `.profile` which doesn't appear either. I found `/etc/profile`, but it says I have no permission to open it.

Could you please help me? I simply need to add a folder to the classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this file doesn't exist by default. The difference between `bash_profile` or `.bashrc` versus `.profile` is that the latter will be read by shells other than bash. For your purposes, you can simply name it `.bashrc`. Open up `Terminal` and enter the following command:

```
cd ~/; touch .bashrc; open -a TextEdit .bashrc
```

Now you have a created a profile, which the bash shell will read from everytime you log into it.

Next, simply enter the variable as plain text in the document:

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/folder
```

Or, if your have a current `$CLASSPATH` that needs to be added to, append the folder to it in your profile:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/folder
```

Save the `.bashrc` file. Exit Terminal and open Terminal back up (or run `. ~/.bashrc` in Terminal without exit/reopen).

To test, enter:

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

Comment: nice, very nice, teacher :)